# Nokogiri: Scrape data being loaded through ajax nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, nokogiri

Is there anyway i can scrape data which is being loaded through ajax calls.
I am using nokogiri with rails 5

Comment: Yes, for example: `doc.search('[style*="display:none"]')`

Comment: it is not working! it always shows nil data

Comment: maybe there's a space after the `:`